# JavaScript Must Be Enabled to View This Email Address

Tags: members, email, mx-notify

I am using the MX Notify Control plugin to email when a new member registers, the template I am using for the email is simply:

```
<strong>Email:</strong>{email}<br>

{exp:member:custom_profile_data member_id="{member_id}"}

<strong>First Name:</strong> {member_firstname}<br>

<strong>Last Name:</strong> {member_lastname}<br>

<strong>ZipCode:</strong> {member_zipcode}<br>

{/exp:member:custom_profile_data}
```

Yet for some reason, when I send it like this, the email is blank.  I used the Simple Registration plugin to create the form.

Then I tried:

```
{exp:member:custom_profile_data member_id="{member_id}"}

<strong>First Name:</strong> {member_firstname}<br>

<strong>Last Name:</strong> {member_lastname}<br>

<strong>Email:</strong>{email}<br>

<strong>ZipCode:</strong> {member_zipcode}<br>

{/exp:member:custom_profile_data}
```

And I get the following error:
 .(JavaScript must be enabled to view this email address)

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That plugin is **2** years old, and appears un-maintained.

Go with Freemember, my friend.

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freemember

I know for a fact the registration form tag works on EE 2.10.1 (source: me! I'm a professional developer. But more importantly, I have it working in an EE 2.10.1 app).

Comment: I assume you mean SimpleRegistration?
I honestly had to use Simple Registration because Freemember requires people to input a password.

Comment: Although I haven't used this addon with free member, I do have it in the wild in a few places: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-auto-password

Comment: I will give this a shot! But it would require me to overhaul everything I already built so I was hoping for a way to just prevent auto linking of email in the system emails.

Comment: Examine these addons carefully before investing your time! I believe they will potentially solve your issues, but you need to decide for yourself.